# Set new user permissions in Yocto recipe

Tags: yocto

I have a recipe to add a user called `foo`:

```sh
inherit useradd
USERADD_PACKAGES = "${PN}"

USERADD_PARAM_${PN} = "-P foo -u 1000 -d /home/foo -r -s /bin/bash foo;"

LICENSE = "CLOSED"

do_install () {
  install -d ${D}/data/docker

  install -d ${D}/home/foo
  chown -R foo ${D}/home/foo
  chown -R foo ${D}/data/docker
}

FILES_${PN} = " \
  /home/foo \
  /data \
"
```

For an obscure reason, `data/docker` is owned by foo but not `/home/foo`. Any idea why?

Comment: What does the -P option?

Comment: set the password

Comment: Shouldn't it be lower case?

Comment: Have you checkd out the answer? Have it worked?

Comment: I checked, I tried, permissions were still wrong. I'm atm testing with the -p instead, maybe this was doing crap...

Comment: You can also try adding the `-m` before `-d /home/foo`.

Comment: I think I found the reason, I'll keep you posted

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need to install `/home/foo`(nor chown) since that task should be already accomplished by useradd, thus you can remove those commands. However, you might want to modify your recipe as follows:

```
do_install () {
    install -d -m 755 ${D}${datadir}/foo
    install -d -m 755 ${D}/data/docker
    chown -R foo ${D}${datadir}/foo
    chown -R foo ${D}/data/docker
}

FILES_${PN} = "${datadir}/foo/* /data/docker/*"
```

Answer (score 0):

So the reason was that another recipe was creating a subfolder in the home directory first and was owned by root by default.

When the recipe to add the user was baked, the home folder was already created with root permissions.

My solution was to add the creation of this folder in the recipe adding the user instead.

Thanks @danior for the corrections